# Write Properties to URL

Tags: java, url, properties

I am trying to the properties from java.util.Properties to a online file using its URL.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public static boolean savePropertiesToURL(Properties properties, String link, String fileName) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (properties != null && link != null && fileName != null) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            try {
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                try {
                    OutputStream outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                    try {
                        properties.store(outStream, fileName);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.err.println("Unable to store the properties: " + ex.getMessage());
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            outStream.flush();
                            result = true;
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(PropertiesUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            System.err.println("Unable to flush outputstream: " + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                        outStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to get outputstream: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Unable to open URL connexion: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.err.println("The URL hasn't been created: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It goes thru all that and returns true. Even tho the file is not written.
There are loggers in every catch, but no catch is ever triggered.

Comment: This code would be much clearer if you used `return false` instead of `result = false`, and so avoided all these nested `if` statements.

Comment: Dude, I hope you're not using that kind of error handling on the daily, that seems like such a pain in the ass ! If you're just going to interrupt the execution flow when you catch an error, why not let it throw and naturally interrupt the execution flow? Or if your method must not throw, just do one big catch all

Comment: @khelwood Sure, I can change that. But I don't think the end result will change. I'll try

Comment: Also you're using a variable called `url`, a variable called `URL` and the class `URL` all in one method. More creative variable names might avoid some confusion.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that `Properties` are made to write to a file (they'll just write `key=value\n` to their `OutputStream`), but URL endpoints aren't generally made to handle that kind of data ; there must be a server answering to the URL, and it must not like what you're sending to it.

Comment: @Aaron How do you want to handle the error and debug if you just put one big try and catch? That's the only way I figured out

Comment: Depends on what kind of handling you want to do. With the previous version of your code all you did was stop the execution by using `if` blocks, but execution would be stopped anyway if you hadn't caught the errors. If you want to do something specific, catch, do it and either return or rethrow to avoid running the rest of the code. If you don't want to do anything specific either don't catch if you can change your method signature or use a single catch that will just return an error value if you can't.